# ejecutar función en un boton generado dinamicamente no funciona en archivo externo y si en <head>

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen día, he generado una serie de X botones dinámicamente, y necesito que al dar clic en uno de ellos me capture el `id` para luego hacer otras cosas, esos botones están en una taba la cual alimento de manera dinámica así:

```
$("#tabla_ordenes_del_cliente").append("
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button onclick='generar_remision(this)' id='"+respuesta[i]['num_pedido']+"'>Generar esta remision</button>
    </td>
  </tr>"
);
```

los id los traigo de una consulta `MySql` por `ajax` lo cual funciona bien y no viene al caso, la cuestión es que me genera los botones perfectamente, miro el inspector de un botón (ejemplo el del id 3) y efectivamente está bien, por ejemplo:

```
<button onclick="generar_remision(this)" id="3">Generar esta remision</button>
```

Lo extraño aquí es que si pongo el código a ejecutarse dentro del `<head>` funciona bien

```
<script>
  function generar_remision(boton)
  {
    let num_pedido=boton.id;
    alert("presionaste el boton de id "+num_pedido);
  }
</script>
```

Pero como todo el proyecto lo hago en archivos externos dentro de una carpeta llamada `js` para mas organización, no funciona, ya me cercioré que estuviese bien incluido y que el nombre del archivo este correcto y en la carpeta correcta pues ahí tengo todos los `js` de todo el proyecto.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/generar_remision.js"></script>
```

El error que me muestra en consola es:

> ReferenceError: generar_remision is not defined[Saber más] panel_de_control.php:1:1

Donde `panel_de_control.php:1:1` es la etiqueta `<html>` y no le encuentro el sentido, se que puedo poner la función dentro de `<head>` y funciona, pero quizá mas adelante necesite mas funciones con botones dinámicos y sería mas desorden que esas funciones estén en `<head>` y no dentro de la carpeta `js` como todos los demás, alguna idea?

Comment: Creo que hace falta un poco mas de información, quizás mostrar el código del archivo js y el html donde le llamas (incluyendo los elementos con los que interactua)

Comment: Abre y mira que `generar_remision.js` no tenga las etiquetas `<script></script>` (ya es un js, no las necesita)

Comment: Seguramente sea problemas de carga de js (posiciones a la hora de cargar las librerías), sería de mucha ayuda ver la estructura `HTML` con todo incluido.